# Getting the resource path of the java project from a custom gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Trying to create a custom gradle plugin in java, how do i get the resources path from inside the task class?

```
public class MyCustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  @Override
  public void apply(Project project) {
    project.getTasks().register("doStuff", CustomTask.class);
  }
}
```

```
public class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {

  // How do I get java project resources dir from here?
  @Inject
  public CustomTask(ProjectLayout projectLayout) {
    directoryProperty = projectLayout.getBuildDirectory();
  }

  @TaskAction
  public void execute() {
    ...
  }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to not get the directory inside the task, because the plugin that provides it might not be applied. Instead I would do it from within your plugin that registers the task, this way you can also ensure that the necessary plugin is actually applied. Gradle will display an error if the task is used without a value being assigned to the input that explains that nothing was assigned.

With the `kotlin-dsl`:

```kotlin
@CacheableTask
abstract class CustomTask : DefaultTask() {
    @get:InputFiles
    abstract val resources: FileCollection
    //...
}
```

I cannot answer if `@InputFiles` is the right annotation for your use case, because I don't know what you want to do with the resource. Refer to the Gradle documentation for more information on the available annotations, and what they do.

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
}

tasks.register<CustomTask>("customTask") {
    resources.set(sourceSets.main.map { it.resources })
}
```

Notice the `map {}` which ensures that our task has a dependency on the `processResources` task, this is done automatically for us because we stick to the provider API of Gradle for everything.

Note that the resources are by default in one directory, but they don't have to be. This is why the resources are defined as `SourceDirectorySet` and not as `Provider<Directory>`. The same is true for anything that originates from the `SourceSetContainer`. It is easier to explain with Java source code: imagine you have Java and Kotlin, then you will have `src/main/java` and `src/main/kotlin`, hence, 2 directories. The former will have a `**/*.java` include filter, whereas the latter has a `**/*.kt` includes filter. If we just want to get all sources then we use `sourceSets.main.map { it.java.sourceDirectories }`, and if we want to get one of both it gets complicated.

Answer (score 2):

First, you'd have to ensure this is a Java project: either applying the `"java"` plugin from your plugin (`project.getPluginManager().apply("java")`), or only registering the task when the `"java"` plugin has been applied by the user (`project.getPluginManager().withPlugin("java", ignored -> { project.getTasks().register(…); });`).

You could then get the resources from the main source set:

```java
SourceSetContainer sourceSets = project.getExtensions().getByType(SourceSetContainer.class);
// Use named() instead of get() if you prefer/need to use providers
SourceSet mainSourceSet = sourceSets.get(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME);
SourceDirectorySet resources = mainSourceSet.getResources();
```

BTW, the best practice is to have tasks only declare their inputs and outputs (e.g. I need a set of directories, or files, as inputs, and my outputs will be one single file, or in one single directory) and have the actual wiring with *default* values be done by the plugin.
You could have the plugin unconditionally register the task, then conditionally when the `"java"` plugin is applied configure its inputs to the project resources; or conditionally register the task or unconditionally apply the `"java"` plugin, as I showed above.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the sources through the `project.sourceSets`.

```
@Inject
  public CustomTask(Project project) {
    directoryProperty = project.projectLayout.getBuildDirectory();
    sourceSet = project.sourceSets.main
  }
```

See also the reference documentation here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout